# Kaizala Employee Leaderboard solution not showing Immersive View

Tags: kaizala, kaizala-action

I was implementing a Kaizala Employee Leader board Solution where I had to connect Kaizala with Flow and Excel. The connections were successful and the Flow worked. The Chat Card showed the results needed. However, the Immersive View did not show up. I have attached images of the two views(Chat Card View and Immersive View) and they look exactly the same as the Chat Card View. It looks like the Immersive View isn't active.

[Immersive View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1RiA.png)

[Chat Card View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4uuG.png)

Answer (score 0):

This issue was seen in old Android Web Views. We have fixed the same.
Some other common reasons for immersive view not showing my performance tab could be:

1. User opening card is not a part of the leaderboard
2. Bad phone number formatting - make sure to include '+' and the country code

before phone number